# Python logging: Why is __init__ called twice?

Tags: python, logging, handler, config, init

I am trying to use python logging with a config file and an own handler. This works to some degree. What really puzzle me is `__init__` being called twice and `__del__` being called once. When I remove the whole config file stuff and create the handler directly within the code `__init__` is called once and `__del__` is never called.

My questions:

1. Why is `__init__` called twice?
2. Why is `__del__` called less often than `__init__`?

The code:

```
#!/bin/env python

import logging
import logging.handlers
import logging.config

class Test1TimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self,filename):
        print "init called"
        logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(self,filename, when='S', interval=86400, backupCount=8, encoding=None)

    def __del__(self):
        print "del called"
        if hasattr(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler,"__del__"):
            logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.__del__(self)

logging.config.fileConfig('/root/test1.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger("test1")
```

The config file:

```
[formatters]
keys: simple

[handlers]
keys: file

[loggers]
keys: root

[formatter_simple]
format: "%(message)s"

[handler_file]
class: test1.Test1TimedRotatingFileHandler
args: ("/root/test1.log",)
level=INFO

[logger_root]
level: INFO
handlers: file
qualname: test1
```

Output looks like this:

```
init called
init called
del called
```

Using the debugger to get the stack trace as suggested by Sentinal reveals this:

First call:

```
> /root/test1.py(12)__init__()
-> print "init called"
(Pdb) where
  /root/test1.py(21)<module>()
-> logging.config.fileConfig('/root/test1.conf')
  /usr/local/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/logging/config.py(84)fileConfig()
-> handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  /usr/local/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/logging/config.py(156)_install_handlers()
-> klass = _resolve(klass)
  /usr/local/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/logging/config.py(94)_resolve()
-> found = __import__(used)
  /root/test1.py(21)<module>()
-> logging.config.fileConfig('/root/test1.conf')
  /usr/local/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/logging/config.py(84)fileConfig()
-> handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  /usr/local/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/logging/config.py(159)_install_handlers()
-> h = klass(*args)
> /root/test1.py(12)__init__()
-> print "init called"
(Pdb) c
init called
```

Second call:

```
> /root/test1.py(12)__init__()
-> print "init called"
(Pdb) w
  /root/test1.py(21)<module>()
-> logging.config.fileConfig('/root/test1.conf')
  /usr/local/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/logging/config.py(84)fileConfig()
-> handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  /usr/local/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/logging/config.py(159)_install_handlers()
-> h = klass(*args)
> /root/test1.py(12)__init__()
-> print "init called"
```

Comment: """Why is init called twice?""" - take the debugger and check why it is called twice. Looking at the call stack can be helpful...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> 1. Why is init called twice?

If you follow the code of the `logging` module, you'll see that when you're loading the logging configuration file, it instantiates all the handlers (First instantiation).

In your code, you declare your handler like `test1.Test1TimedRotatingFileHandler`, so when it try to import your handler, it parses the code in the test1 module... so it recreates the handler !!

Corrected code will guard using `__name__ == '__main__'`:

```
#!/bin/env python

import logging
import logging.handlers
import logging.config

class Test1TimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self,filename):
        print "init called"
        logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(self,filename, when='S', interval=86400, backupCount=8, encoding=None)

    def __del__(self):
        print "del called"
        if hasattr(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler,"__del__"):
            logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.__del__(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.config.fileConfig('./test1.conf')
    logger = logging.getLogger("test1")
```

> 2 . Why is del called less often than init?

In general, the `__del__` operator is called when-python-wants, more exactly, it is called when the garbage collector decides to garbage-collect the object; this is not necessarily just after you release it.

Comment: And the destructor is not necessarily called when Python exits.

Comment: @Cedric: Especially when handling rotation logfiles it is kind of counter productive when the constructor is called twice. I was planning to do a doRollover() in the constructor of my handler. When init is called twice this results in two rollovers... So what to do? Is this a bug, a feature or what?

Comment: not really a bug, python only keeps 1 handler, the other one seems to be "lost"...

Comment: @Cedric_ Thx. Do you have any suggestions how to come over that?

Comment: Heh, I think you fixed your answer while I was reading the logging code and working on mine :)

Answer (score 5):

You are missing an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard around your logging configuration code. It is getting executed a second time when `logging` imports your `test1` module to find the class reference.

Alternatively, use the name `__main__.Test1TimedRotatingFileHandler` in the config file, or else put the configuration code and the handler class in different files.