# Why is __init__ not called after __new__ SOMETIMES

Tags: python, genshi

Let me start with this is not a repeat of 
[Why does __init__ not get called if __new__ called with no args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903355/why-does-init-not-get-called-if-new-called-with-no-args).  I have tried to carefully construct some sample code for `__new__` and `__init__` that has no explanation I can find.

The basic parameters:

- There is a base class called NotMine as it comes from another library (I'll disclose at the end, not important here)
- That class has an `__init__` method that in turn calls a `_parse` method
- I need to override the `_parse` method in subclasses
- which subclass I'm creating is not known until invocation
- I know there are factory design methods but I cannot use them here (More at the end)
- I have tried to make careful use of `super` to avoid the problems in
  [Python logging: Why is __init__ called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032053/python-logging-why-is-init-called-twice)
- I know this is also 'kind of' an AbstractBaseMehtod opportunity but that did not help

Anyway, `__init__` should be called after `__new__` and for every explanation of why SOME samples below don't work I seem to be able to point to other cases that do work and rule out the explanation.

```
class NotMine(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "NotMine __init__"
        self._parse()

    def _parse(self):
        print "NotMine _parse"

class ABC(NotMine):
    def __new__(cls,name,*args, **kwargs):
        print "-"*80
        print "Entered through the front door ABC.__new__(%s,%s,*%s,**%s)"%(cls,name,args,kwargs)
        if name == 'AA':
            obj = super(NotMine,ABC).__new__(AA,*args,**kwargs)
            print "Exiting door number 1 with an instance of: %s"%type(obj)
            return obj 
        elif name == 'BB':
            obj = super(NotMine,ABC).__new__(BB,*args,**kwargs)
            print "Exiting door number 2 with an instance of: %s"%type(obj)
            return obj
        else:
            obj = super(NotMine,ABC).__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
            print "Exiting door number 3 with an instance of: %s"%type(obj)
            return obj

class AA(ABC):

    def _parse(self):
       print "AA _parse"

class BB(ABC):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        print "BB_init:*%s, **%s"%(args,kw)        
        super(BB,self).__init__(self,*args,**kw)

    def _parse(self):
        print "BB _parse"

class CCC(AA):

    def _parse(self):
        print "CCCC _parse"


print("########### Starting with ABC always calls __init__ ############")
ABC("AA")            # case 1
ABC("BB")            # case 2
ABC("NOT_AA_OR_BB")  # case 3

print("########### These also all call __init__ ############")
AA("AA")           # case 4
BB("BB")           # case 5
AA("NOT_AA_OR_BB") # case 6
BB("NOT_AA_OR_BB") # case 7
CCC("ANYTHING")    # case 8

print("########### WHY DO THESE NOT CALL __init__ ############")
AA("BB")  # case 9  
BB("AA")  # case 10
CCC("BB") # case 11
```

If you execute the code, you can see that for each call to `__new__` it announces "which door" it is exiting through and with what type.   I can exit the same "door" with the same "type" object and have `__init__` called in one case and not the other.  I've looked at the mro of the "calling" class and that offers no insight since I can invoke that class ( or a subcass as in CCC ) and have `__init__` called.

**End Notes:**
The `NotMine` library I'm using is the [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) MarkupTemplate and the reason for not using a Factory design method is that their TemplateLoader needs a defaultClass to construct.  I don't know until I start parsing, which I do in `__new__`.  There is a lot of cool voodoo magic that genshi loaders and templates do that make this worth the effort.

I can run an unmodified instance of their loader and currently everything works as long as I ONLY pass the ABC (abstract sort-of-factory) class as the default.  Things are working well but this unexplained behavior is an almost certain bug later.

**UPDATE:**
Ignacio, nailed the top line question, if the returned object is not an "instance of" *cls* then `__init__` is not called.  I do find that calling the "constructor" (e.g. `AA(args..)` is wrong as it will call `__new__` again and you are right back where you started.  You could modify an arg to take a different path.  That just means you call `ABC.__new__` twice rather than infinitely.  A working solution is to edit `class ABC` above as:

```
class ABC(NotMine):
  def __new__(cls,name,*args, **kwargs):
    print "-"*80
    print "Entered through the front door ABC.__new__(%s,%s,*%s,**%s)"%(cls,name,args,kwargs)
    if name == 'AA':
        obj = super(NotMine,ABC).__new__(AA,*args,**kwargs)
        print "Exiting door number 1 with an instance of: %s"%type(obj)
    elif name == 'BB':
        obj = super(NotMine,ABC).__new__(BB,*args,**kwargs)
        print "Exiting door number 2 with an instance of: %s"%type(obj)
    elif name == 'CCC':
        obj = super(NotMine,ABC).__new__(CCC,*args,**kwargs)
        print "Exiting door number 3 with an instance of: %s"%type(obj)
    else:
        obj = super(NotMine,ABC).__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
        print "Exiting door number 4 with an instance of: %s"%type(obj)
    ## Addition to decide who calls __init__  ##
    if isinstance(obj,cls):
        print "this IS an instance of %s So call your own dam __init__"%cls
        return obj
    print "this is NOT an instance of %s So __new__ will call __init__ for you"%cls
    obj.__init__(name,*args, **kwargs)
    return obj

print("########### now, these DO CALL __init__ ############")
AA("BB")  # case 9  
BB("AA")  # case 10
CCC("BB") # case 11
```

Notice the last few lines.  Not calling `__init__` if it's a "different" class does not make sense to me, ESPECIALLY when the "different" class is still a subclass of the class calling `__init__`.  I don't like the above edit but least I get the rules a little better now.

Comment: Is Genshi using a metaclass? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python

Comment: No, My sample code does not use the genshi as a base.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

This is to allow `__new__()` to [return a new instance of a *different* class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859158/20862), which has its own `__init__()` to be called instead. You will need to detect if you're creating a new cls, and call the appropriate constructor instead if not.

Comment: OK, I kind of get the super literal "does not return an instance of cls". But, I am returning a new instance of a different class, which has it's own `__init__` but it doesn't get called, even if it's a common base (in the old mro).  Am **I** supposed to call it in new??

Comment: You're supposed to *instantiate* it in `__new__()`, by calling its constructor.

Comment: ouch. Bad idea here. I thought this might lead to the "called twice" problem I quoted above but since ABC is a common base, calling the constructor in the code causes a recursive call to `__new__` and hangs the session :-(

Comment: Then you're doing the check between `cls` and `name` incorrectly.

Comment: The check between *cls* and name was not an issue and the constructor still seems wrong ... see my edit above. That being said, you did answer my top line question exactly, which put me back on track. THANKS

Comment: I don't agree with your fix, for two reasons: 1) `CCC('CCC')` will infinitely recurse; 2) there is a lot of duplicated code. Better to pick the new class based on the argument, then check if `cls` and the new class are the same.

Comment: re: 1) you were absolutely correct.  I left that over from testing the case and I've edited the fix to fix it so thx.  re: 2) "better" here is subjective. "check if `cls` and the new class are the same"?  obj could be an instance of a subclass of `cls` or `super __new__` could return something else.  Anyway, my actual code does other stuff (loading modules etc.) which makes the above fix "better" ... for me ... for this case ... i think

Answer (score -1):

Just my two cents here, but why don't you use Python duck typing to provide Genshi with something that behaves like a class ?

I took a quick look at Genshi [source code](http://genshi.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/genshi/template/loader.py) and the only requirements that I saw on the 'class' parameter to the TemplateLoader is that it is callable with the given arguments.

I think it would be easier to mock a class with a factory function returning the actual created instance.

Comment: yes, deep in the source it eventually calls the constructor on the default_class which could be any callable. I think this would be a viable alternative.  The future could be different and it "seems" that passing a subclass of MarkupTemplate is the right OO thing to do.  But the again it "seemed" to me that `__new__` should have behaved differently so who am I to speak ;-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question that was asked.