# Python: How to understand __new__ as defined in the built-in object class?

Tags: python, class, object, pycharm, instantiation

First of all, this is not a duplication of [Why is __init__ not called after __new__ SOMETIMES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367126/why-is-init-not-called-after-new-sometimes) because this question really is about the implementation of the build-in `object` class.

Here is the full story:

I am learning about `__new__` vs `__init__` in python. Here is the example I've tried:

```
class A(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        print("A.__new__ called")
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__ called")

A()
print('finished')
```

The output is

```
A.__new__ called
A.__init__ called
finished
```

I understand that `__new__` does object creation and `__init__` does object initialization.

`__new__` is called automatically when calling the class name. Then `__init__` is called every time an instance of the class is returned by `__new__`, passing the returned instance to `__init__` as the `self` parameter.

Knowing this, if we have a bad `__new__` function that does not create and return an object instance, then `__init__` would not be called:

```
class A(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        print("A.__new__ called")
        #return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__ called")

A()
```

Note that the `__new__` method only prints a string. It does not return anything so `__init__` has nothing to pick up. And indeed the output confirms this:

```
A.__new__ called
finished
```

`"A.__init__ called"` is never printed so `__init__` is indeed never called.

Now if we do not define a `__new__` method (this is 99% of the common use case. programmers rarely need to define this method), then the father's `__new__` is called by default. e.g.

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__ called")

A()
print('finished')
```

output is:

```
A.__init__ called
finished
```

In this case the `__new__` of built-in `object` class is called.

BUT, as I looked at the how the built-in `object` class is defined, I see this:

```
class object:
    """ The most base type """
    def __delattr__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        """ Implement delattr(self, name). """
        pass
    ...
    ...
    ...

     @staticmethod # known case of __new__
     def __new__(cls, *more): # known special case of object.__new__
         """ Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature. """
         pass
```

NOTHING is implemented in the `__new__`!  There is just a `pass` sitting inside !!??

How is this making sense?

Comment: That's not the actual Implementation. It seems like these are just stubs for the signature. Is this pycharm?

Comment: @MSeifert
Yes this is pycharm. Do you know where I can find the actual implementation then?

Comment: @MadisonCourto How is that a duplicate of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the Cpython implementation is written in C so PyCharm cannot navigate to the source code because it is compiled. However it can and does display stubs that emulate the signature.

The source code for `object.__new__` for 3.7.3 can be found in their Github repository: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L3671-L3732

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I think I've digged deep enough, to the level where I cannot keep digging anymore. (Unless I have the time to learn all about C and read through the C implementation).